# How to handle removed documents after executes the #query on Mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am removing documents found from an array of one `param` (in this case called *slug*):

```
const selected = ['abc_1', 'aaa_2', ...]

MyModel.remove({'slug': { $in: selected }}, (err, data) => {
  if (err || data === null){
    next(err)
  }
  res.json(data)
});
```

#### Problem:

Want to preserve the **removed** `Objects` like what happens using `doc` param in `findOneAndRemove()` callback, that is:

> the document before updates are applied if `new: false`, or after updates if `new = true`.

---

#### Custom solution (using *Promises*)

This *solution* works but I found dirty and a little verbose (since, I think, executes two times a *similar* query):

```
const selected = ['abc_1', 'aaa_2', ...]

MyModel.find({'slug': { $in: selected }})
  .then(orig => {
    MyModel.remove({'slug': { $in: selected }}, (err, data) => {
      if (err || data === null){
        next(err);
      }

      console.log('Array of Objects deleted recently:', orig);
      res.json(data)
    });
  })
```

---

#### Question

Since the `remove()` callback seems to return a `result` Object with information like `result.n` (quantity) etc, but not the original document `Object`s **is there a better/correct way to handle this situation?**

Answer (score 0):

One possible improvement could be using the ids to delete the documents. It should be faster.

```
const selected = ['abc_1', 'aaa_2', ...]

MyModel.find({'slug': { $in: selected }})
  .then(orig => {
    const ids = orig.map(o => o._id);
    MyModel.remove({'_id': { $in: ids }}, (err, data) => {
      if (err || data === null){
        next(err);
      }

      console.log('Array of Objects deleted recently:', orig);
      res.json(data)
    });
  })
```

Comment: thank you @amiram-korach for the reply, I'll try this improvement for sure; but mostly interested in how to avoid `MyModel.find()` => `then()` => `MyModel.remove()` that seems a bit verbose.

Comment: Don't think you have a choice.